# Geth syncing gets close to latest block and then stops

Tags: synchronization, chaindata

I have a new node that gets close to the latest block and then stops syncing.  Each time I stop and then restart geth, it will sync back up to about 75 to 100 blocks away from the latest block and then stop.  The only way to get it close to the latest block again is to stop and start geth.

my geth command:

```
sudo geth --datadir "/data/.ethereum" --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain * --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3
```

Examining my chaindata shows that it is about 32G, which seems small but I don't know how large it should be.

```
du -sh /data/.ethereum/geth/chaindata/
```

32G     /data/.ethereum/geth/chaindata/

I've also ensured that my time is synced up with:

```
timedatectl
```

shows

```
      Local time: Mon 2017-11-06 17:14:48 UTC
  Universal time: Mon 2017-11-06 17:14:48 UTC
        RTC time: Mon 2017-11-06 17:14:48
       Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was actually not a problem.  I left it alone for about 3 hours and now everything is synced properly.